# Command works on terminal but not with shortcut

Tags: command-line-interface, shortcut, linux-mint

Using Linux Mint 18.1, the following command works perfectly from the command line:

```
cb date +%Y-%m-%d
```

This command copies today's date to the clipboard. The `cb` comes from [this article](http://madebynathan.com/2011/10/04/a-nicer-way-to-use-xclip/), and I've placed the code on my .zshrc file. The command works perfectly from the command line, whether I run it like that, preceded by `sh` or `zsh`, or with an alias.

If I try to create a custom shortcut to any command using the GUI at keyboard/shortcuts, however, the command will fail with the following message: "failed to execute child process 'cb' (no such file or process)." Any thoughts on what might be the underlying problem and how to fix it?

Comment: @halfer, I changed my question to a more reproducible example, please see whether that helps

Comment: @halfer i just added the explanation.

Comment: @halfer yes, it means that it sends the output to the clipboard